# Things you can do with Flexbox that were impossible without it

Tags: css, flexbox

What are the completely new things you can do with Flexbox which you wouldn't be able to do before in any way using only CSS (without markup changes). I understand Flexbox makes many layout issues much more straightforward and easier to maintain, but am also interested in knowing what unique features it brings that were completely impossible before. After reading some articles I still can't crystallise any thorough list in my mind, so far being able to come up only with 2:

- Layout mixing items with fixed and relative sizes. In many cases it could be done using `calc` function (though it will quickly become messy), but I think some borderline cases can't be make up for without adding extra markup (or am I wrong an it can?)
- Displaying things in the order completely independent from the source order

Comment: Why is this even getting up-votes? Its not really a question that is suitable on SO. Too broad.

Comment: another helpful feature is `align-items: center; `

Comment: @Ruddy: Because people think it's a useful question, and I have to agree, even if it may seem potentially broad. Off-topic doesn't automatically equal bad.

Comment: Off topic questions are exactly that. Off topic. Hence, in this context, it is a bad question is it not @BoltClock?

Comment: @BoltClock Guess thats fair enough, just not usually how I see this site react to such questions.

Comment: @jbutler483: You could say that it's a bad *fit* for the site, but that doesn't make it a bad question in itself. Just my opinion though.

Comment: This question is necessary evil.

Comment: @BoltClock: I would agree that it is a well structured question, but I don't think it's been posted in the right place, that's all.

Comment: @jbutler483: Exactly. I'm sorta on the fence on this one considering I've answered similar questions in the past, however, hence abstaining from close-voting.

Comment: It sems I'm a little misinformed, so please clarify for me what are the questions suitable for this site. I used to think these are all questions that are specific, without asking for opinions.

Comment: @maioman Isn't `align-items: center` the same as `vertical-align: middle`? And if you mean vertical centering of a child, then it can be done without Flexbox, though was definetely way too complicated.

Comment: @Robert: Your question is specific, but it essentially asks for a list of possibilities which can be expressed in a number of separate answers - none of which can be marked as a single correct answer - or alternatively a single monolithic list answer.

Comment: @BoltClock Okay, I get it now, thanks. Do you think I should delete the question?